# Why does 就范 mean "to give in"?

Tags: meaning, etymology

What is the etymology of this word?

As far as I know 就 means:

**to start** or **to enter**, which sometimes is being interpreted as **to take** some thing (to enter a position of...)

So I just can't see why "surrender". Maybe there is some story to that word?

Answer (score 4):

就 here means 迁就，将就, *"to accept"* in english

范 here means *"standard, model*"; in history 范 is the model to cast iron.

So 就范 means *"fit in a model"* (given by others) in very strict way from the original meaning. It's a strong word, you can understand it as *"surrender"*.

Comment: So it is not "surrender to enemy" but "to surrender to pressure (when someone is trying to make you do somethig)"? Hmm... interesting. So it's like "to swallow (to take in) your pride"

Comment: yes, kinda like that.

Comment: Ok. Now I think I got this. 就范 means "to take shape". As you said "as in casting iron". Thanks a lot!

Comment: @coobit 就范 is more factual than perceptional, forcibly surrender rather than swallow pride.

Comment: It can also mean surrender to enemy.